# How to advertise a free e-book?

Tags: self-publishing, ebook, marketing

I've created a free e-book in online HTML, EPUB, MOBI, and PDF formats.

I've created a small site to advertise this book and an other site (currently supports forums) for the community of readers of my book. Also I have a blog related with this book.

Now, which directories/catalogues/resources should I submit my book to? The purpose is to increase readership.

Comment: What genre/kind of book is it?

Comment: Publish it on iBookstore and Amazon. You can publish it for free on their sites. In the meantime, if you know a blogger or two, send them a copy and ask them to review it for you.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few organizations that focus on getting new authors introduced to more readers, the one I am mainly associated with is http://bookhubinc.wordpress.com/ . Basically contact them and say that you're a writer having writen a new free book and would like help getting it known. They normally respond quickly. You don't have to use them or feel restricted to only use them. You may contact other organisations that offer the same service. Book Hub also distributes a collection of books to reviewers who run blogs for them to review so the book becomes more widely known. Alternitvly you may decide to skip the middle man and go straight to the reviewers, however using Book Hub you will probably get more reviews.

Comment: What is their incentive to help to advertise a FREE ebook?

Answer (score 1):

These are some websites where you can advertise your e-book for free :

1) http://ebookfreeadvertising.wonderbookland.com/

2) http://www.librarything.com/

3) http://www.scribd.com/

4) http://www.goodreads.com/

5) http://www.wattpad.com/

6) http://authonomy.com/?from=bookarmy

7) http://www.booktalk.org/

8) http://list.ly/list/2hf-top-free-places-to-promote-your-ebook

Answer (score 0):

If you have no Twitter account yet, I highly recommend it. There are a lot of organizations that use twitter to promote products, and one of the companies I follow is freemykindle on Twitter, as well as other Twitter accounts that help promote authors.

Freemykindle specializes in advertising free, or really cheap E-books, and has 1342 followers.